# Silently dropping a nullable database column with slick

Tags: scala, slick

I have a database for objects called `Campaigns` containing three fields :

- Id (int, not nullable)
- Version (int, not nullable)
- Stuff (Text, nullable)

Let's call `CampaignsRow` the corresponding slick entity class

When I select line from Campaigns, I don't always need to read stuff, which contains big chunks of text.

However, I'd very much like to work in the codebase with the class CampaignsRow instead of a tuple, and so to be able to sometimes just drop the Stuff column, while retaining the original type

Basically, I'm trying to write the following function :

```
  //Force dropping the Stuff column from the current Query
  def smallCampaign(campaigns: Query[Campaigns, CampaignsRow, Seq]): Query[Campaigns, CampaignsRow, Seq] = {

    val smallCampaignQuery = campaigns.map {
      row => CampaignsRow(row.id, row.version , None : Option[String]) 
    } 
    smallCampaignQuery /* Fails because the type is now wrong, I have a Query[(Rep[Int], Rep[Int], Rep[Option[String]), (Int, Int, Option[String], Seq] */
  }
```

Any idea how to do this ? I suspect this has to do with Shape in slick, but I can't find a resource to start understanding this class, and the slick source code is proving too complex for me to follow.

Comment: so, I stumbled upon mapTo[], which is not far off (even though it's not exactly the same signature), but using it in my use case breaks the scala compiler in a weird way.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually already doing almost what you want in `def *`, the default mapping. You can use the same tools in the `map` method. Your two tools are `mapTo` and `<>`.

As you've found, there is the `mapTo` method which you can only use if your case class exactly matches the shape of the tuple, so if you wanted a special case class just for this purpose:

```
case class CampaignLite(id: Int, version: Int)

val smallCampaignQuery = campaigns.map {
  row => (row.id, row.version).mapTo[CampaignLite]
}
```

As you want to reuse your existing class, you can write your own convert functions instead of using the standard `tupled` and `unapply` and pass those to `<>`:

```
object CampaignRow {
  def tupleLite(t: (Int, Int)) = CampaignRow(t._1, t._2, None)
  def unapplyLite(c: CampaignRow) = Some((c.id, c.version))
}

val smallCampaignQuery = campaigns.map {
  row => (row.id, row.version) <> (CampaignRow.tupleLite, CampaignRow.unapplyLite)
}
```

This gives you the most flexibility, as you can do whatever you like in your convert functions, but it's a bit more wordy.

As `row` is an instance of the `Campaigns` table you could always define it there alongside `*`, if you need to use it regularly.

```
class Campaigns ... {
  ...
  def * = (id, version, stuff).mapTo[CampaignRow]
  def liteMapping = (id, version) <> (CampaignRow.tupleLite, CampaignRow.unapplyLite)
}

val liteCampaigns = campaigns.map(_.liteMapping)
```

Reference: [Essential Slick 3, section 5.2.1](http://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.pdf)

Comment: Hi ! Thanks a lot for the detailed walkthrough ! However, `val liteCampaigns = campaigns.map(_.lite*)` is typed  `Query[MappedProjection[CampaignRow, (Int, Int)...]` and not `Query[CampaignRow, Campaign, Seq]`, and it seems the former is not castable to the latter ?

Comment: Yeah, welcome to Slick types :) that type makes more sense when you're mapping to a different class, and I guess it's necessary for it to remember how the query works, but generally it's best to be lenient about the exact Query types you're dealing with. If it's any consolation, the `.result` of the query is the same type.

Comment: Indeed. My trouble is that I compose those queries, and I used Query[U,T,Seq] as my function parameters type. Considering this kind of subtlety, it may have been a bad idea. Back to work to clean all this, but it won't be easy (because of course in my real world app I have custom interfaces inheritance restrictions on U and T aha :'( )

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you could consider making `CampaignRow` a case class that models your `Campaigns` table class by having `Campaigns` extend `Table[CampaignRow]` and providing the bidirectional mapping for the `*` projection:

```
case class CampaignRow(id: Int, version: Int, stuff: Option[String])

class Campaigns(tag: Tag) extends Table[CampaignRow](tag, "CAMPAIGNS") {
  // ...
  def * = (id, version, stuff) <> (CampaignRow.tupled, CampaignRow.unapply)
}
```

You should then be able to do something like below:

```
val campaigns = TableQuery[CampaignRow]

val smallCampaignQuery = campaigns.map( _.copy(stuff = None) )
```

For a relevant example, here's a [Slick doc](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/schemas.html#mapped-tables).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I have this exact structure regarding Campaigns and CampaignsRow. And as it happens, copy is available on TableQuery[CampaignsRow], but not on Query[Campaigns, CampaignsRow, Seq]. I'll try to take it from there though !